# Elastic search in Unravel failing with out of memory

Tags: elasticsearch

*Out of memory**

Elastic search service frequently going down.

It consuming more resource and running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with heap memory for elastic search.

Update below value:

Go to /installer/templates/elasticsearch/start.sh.template
Increase HEAP_MB value